# How can I make a responsive css grid (display: grid) that has three equal boxes on the top row and then the rest of the rows are two equal size boxes?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make a responsive css grid that looks like this:

```
box | box | box
b o x  |  b o x
b o x  |  b o x
```

and then when the screen size gets small enough, all of the columns collapse into a single column with each box on its own row.

Is this possible?

Edit:
For anyone who has this issue, changing the number of columns via media query from 6 to 1 was not working. However, I had the idea to make all of the items span 6 columns at the break point and that worked perfectly. This is an addition to the answer given by lawrence-witt and paulie-d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a SIX column grid

```css
.item {
  height: 3em;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 4px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.item:nth-child(1),
.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2
}

.item:nth-child(4),
.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

After that it's just a matter of adding a media query to collapse the grid to a single column at the appropriate breakpoint,

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it using the nth-child feature. To make the grid responsive you simply add a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) that changes the styling of cells and grid at a certain screen width.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.cell:nth-child(1),
.cell:nth-child(2),
.cell:nth-child(3){
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">One</div>
  <div class="cell">Two</div>
  <div class="cell">Three</div>
  <div class="cell">Four</div>
  <div class="cell">Five</div>
  <div class="cell">Six</div>
  <div class="cell">Seven</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You and @paulie-d both had a nearly identical answer. I am choosing yours as the answer to my question because it looks like you answered first.
Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score -1):

By using CSS flex layout and CSS media query you can achieve your need. See the below code, if the screen size reduced to 600px then it will change to single column layout.

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .three-box-row > div {
      width: 33%;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .two-box-row > div {
      width: 49%;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .container {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .container > div {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="three-box-row container">
      <div style="background-color: red;">Box 1</div>
      <div style="background-color: green;">Box 2</div>
      <div style="background-color: blue;">Box 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-box-row container">
      <div style="background-color: red;">Box 1</div>
      <div style="background-color: green;">Box 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-box-row container">
      <div style="background-color: green;">Box 1</div>
      <div style="background-color: blue;">Box 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I am looking for a way to use css grid to achieve this effect.